# Why ths works in anonymous but not in a procedure?

Tags: oracle, plsql, dbms-metadata

If I do the following, everything is fine:

```
declare
  l_foo clob;
begin
select
regexp_replace(
  dbms_metadata.get_ddl('USER', 'SCOTT', null) ||
  dbms_metadata.GET_GRANTED_DDL ('SYSTEM_GRANT', 'SCOTT') ||
  dbms_metadata.GET_GRANTED_DDL ('OBJECT_GRANT', 'SCOTT') ||
  dbms_metadata.GET_GRANTED_DDL ('ROLE_GRANT', 'SCOTT')
,'"' || chr(10), '";' || chr(10)) 
into l_foo 
from dual;
end;
/
```

But if I wrap this in a procedure:

```
create procedure tests is
  l_foo clob;
begin
select
regexp_replace(
  dbms_metadata.get_ddl('USER', 'SCOTT', null) ||
  dbms_metadata.GET_GRANTED_DDL ('SYSTEM_GRANT', 'SCOTT') ||
  dbms_metadata.GET_GRANTED_DDL ('OBJECT_GRANT', 'SCOTT') ||
  dbms_metadata.GET_GRANTED_DDL ('ROLE_GRANT', 'SCOTT')
,'"' || chr(10), '";' || chr(10)) 
into l_foo 
from dual;
end;
/
```

And execute the procedure by "exec tests;" then I catch a object SCOTT of type USER not found in schema SCOTT.

Why is this and how do I get around?

Thanks 
Chris

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oracle [Documentation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_metada.htm#i1016867) states:

> In stored procedures, functions, and
>   definers-rights packages, roles (such
>   as `SELECT_CATALOG_ROLE`) are disabled.
>   Therefore, **such a PL/SQL program can
>   only fetch metadata for objects in its
>   own schema**. If you want to write a
>   PL/SQL program that fetches metadata
>   for objects in a different schema
>   (based on the invoker's possession of
>   `SELECT_CATALOG_ROLE`), you must make
>   the program invokers-rights.

To do this, you must add `authid` to your procedure.

```
create procedure tests authid CURRENT_USER is
  l_foo clob;
begin
select
regexp_replace(
  dbms_metadata.get_ddl('USER', 'SCOTT', null) ||
  dbms_metadata.GET_GRANTED_DDL ('SYSTEM_GRANT', 'SCOTT') ||
  dbms_metadata.GET_GRANTED_DDL ('OBJECT_GRANT', 'SCOTT') ||
  dbms_metadata.GET_GRANTED_DDL ('ROLE_GRANT', 'SCOTT')
,'"' || chr(10), '";' || chr(10)) 
into l_foo 
from dual;
end;
/

SQL> EXEC tests 

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed
```